# Why List == 'Sorted' Keyword gives false

Tags: python, list, sorting

When I check condition of this list `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` and this list `[1,2,3,2,1,5,4]` to 'sorted' keyword means

```
>> a == sorted
>> False
```

why this gives me False and

```
>>a != sorted
>> True
```

why this gives me true? 
it's gives false in '==' and true in '!=' regardless list is sorted or not

Comment: `sorted` is a built-in function, and since a list can never equal a function, `a == sorted` will always return `False`. Therefore, the opposite, `a != sorted`, will always return `True`. `== sorted` is **not** the same as determining whether a list is sorted; you would need to create your own function for that.

Comment: Because `some_list == sorted`, compares your list with the `sorted` *function*, and since a list is something different than a `sorted`, it returns `False`.

Comment: Note that `sorted` is *not* a keyword, it is a builtin function, that is something different.

Comment: it's clear now.. thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sorted` is a built-in function in Python. Lists and functions are inherently incomparable so it's natural that `a == sorted` would return false regardless of what's in `a`. You can check this by using the `type` function:

```
>>> print(type([1, 2, 3]))
<class 'list'>
>>> print(type(sorted))
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

If you wanted to check the "sortedness" of `a`, you would do:

```
a == sorted(a)
```

or, if you prefer something that doesn't run in O(n log n) time:

```
all(first <= second for first, second in zip(a, a[1:]))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `sorted()` function takes a list and returns it sorted.

So you should compare your list to a "sorted version" of that list to see if it was originally sorted.

E.g.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l == sorted(l)
True
>>> l = [2,1,3]
>>> l == sorted(l)
False
```

---

Note that this is slow for long lists as you are generating a new, sorted version in memory. Instead you could write a procedure to check if each element is greater than the previous. This would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the meaning of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). It's a function that returns a sorted list, not a test of whether a given list is sorted. To achieve that you could use something like `a == sorted(a)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at this in a bit of depth:

`sorted` is indeed a keyword but it's not what you think it is:

```
>>> type(sorted)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

so this expression `>>> a == sorted` checks if your list `a` is equal to this `builtin_function_or_method`, it's not checking whether the list is sorted. You will need to write your own sort check, maybe like below:

```
def is_sorted(a=[]):
    prev = a[0]
    if len(a)>1:
        for item in a[1:]:
            if item < prev:
                return False
            else:
                prev=item
    return True
```

and then use that function to make your check like so:

```
>>> is_sorted(a)
>>> True
```

or use `sorted` for it's intended purpose:

```
a==sorted(a)
```